# zsh substitution, can't do regex with repetition

Tags: shell, regex, zsh

I'm trying to perform ZSH variable substitution, but I'm having to do it the lame way, by piping through `cut`. Is it possible to perform this operation entirely within ZSH?

`i=./riak.logs.cloudstoragea08/2014-08-07T15:47:49.540310/console.log.2014-07-31-05
echo ${${i/\.\//}:s/\/*//}
riak.logs.cloudstoragea08/2014-08-07T15:47:49.540310/console.log.2014-07-31-05
echo ${${i/\.\//}}
riak.logs.cloudstoragea08/2014-08-07T15:47:49.540310/console.log.2014-07-31-05
echo ${echo ${i/\.\//} | cut -d/ -f 1}
zsh: bad substitution:
echo $(echo ${i/\.\//} | cut -d/ -f 1)
riak.logs.cloudstoragea08`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=./riak.logs.cloudstoragea08/2014-08-07T15:47:49.540310/console.log.2014-07-31-05
j=${i:2}
echo ${j%%/*}
```

Alternatively:

```
expr $i : '\.\/\([^/]*\)/'
```

Comment: Wait, better - echo ${${i:2}%%/*} - i really wanted to get it nested. Thanks for your help

Comment: You should really break this down. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: @MikeFurlender he's trying to extract the first folder name. In the first example it's cutting the first 2 chars off and then deleting everything from the next `/` until the end. See here for more info http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion In the regex is selecting (with the `\(` and `\)` ) everything between `./` and the next `/`. Since regex try to match the longest, the safest way is to only match characters that are not `/` (with `[^/]` )